# Control Browser Clock

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Is it possible with **testcafe** control browser clock?
In my case, I schedule a 30 minutes timeout and would like to test if after the 30 minutes the timeout is executed and obviously I want contorl the browser clock to avoid to get my test running by 30 minutes.
Sugestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestCafe doesn't control the internal browser clock. I guess you should rethink your test case because it does not make sense to test the built-in browser functionality.

Comment: I think I get it. Do you mean that my test even being a user flow should not test a built in func, right?
But how to simulate a user flow when I have the following scenario:
- user login
- after 25 minutes warn the user with: session will expire in 5 minute
- after 30 minutes warn the user with: session expired You'll be redirected to some cool page

Comment: @djornada It's an interesting scenario. AFAIK, no one E2E testing framework supports it at the moment. You can send a feature request to the testcafe repository on GitHub using [this form](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=feature_request.md).

Comment: @AlexeyLindberg do you know if we have a way to control the browser clock? no necessary using testcafe. I have no ideia how to do it

Answer (score 1):

As sugested by @AlexeyLindberg I opened an issue on [test cafe github repo #5098](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5098)